# Multiple sites amazon ws windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new with the amazon servers created my instance yesterday and is working with my site there.

However wanted to put more than one site, anyone know of any tutorial or something parecedido for the Windows version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serve any number of sites from an EC2 instace. You just need to point the domain name to the same instance using the DNS. You can use Route53 from AWS as the DNS: http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/